# Windows Forms: "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid." coming from System stack

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, gdi

The unhandled exception handler on one of our in-house WinForms apps is regularly reporting this error, and variations of the same, from use in production (we have it configured to email us whenever an unhandled exception occurs). However it's not reproducible and occurs at random intervals on different users machines, which are all XP SP3.

It appears to be related to Masked text boxes in datagrids, but it only seems to appear in the same three controls, out of dozens on many screens. These controls don't have any Font specified.

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight(Graphics graphics)
   at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight()
   at System.Drawing.Font.get_Height()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Font(Font value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.BeginEditInternal(Boolean selectAll)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam,
IntPtr lparam)
```

The thing that really has me stumped is that the stack trace is completely within the System namespace, so there's something wrong with a font, but we have no idea what it is. "Parameter is not valid" doesn't give a lot of information about what is invalid about the parameter (this is from the underlying GDI library).

We also get a similar exception that travels through one of our classes, which has allowed me to trap the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight(Graphics graphics)
   at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight()
   at System.Drawing.Font.get_Height()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Font(Font value)
   at MyApp.MaskedTextBoxEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle
dataGridViewCellStyle)
```

The code in question is merely this:

```
public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle){
  this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font; 
  // set other things
}
```

I wrapped that line in a try/catch block and called a ToString() on the passed Font, and got the following: "[Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8.25, Units=3,GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]", so I can't figure out what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you catch the exception add more data to it and rethrow it? I suspect the error only happens in specific records based on the underlying data maybe a null field ?

Comment: Exception has a dictionary where you can add objects to it adjust your error handler to report these

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** 
The common reason for this error is that you are passing invalid value as parameter to your function. My assumption is that you are calling your method something like this

```
  ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(getStyleFromSomeWhere);
```

Now in the above example **getStyleFromSomeWhere** is invalid thus throwing the exception

**Solution:**

The best solution here is that when ever you get this exception (and you get email) you send the parameter to yourself as well. This way you can diagnose what are the values of parameter when the exception occurred and diagnose the root cause.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response, but if you read my question you'll see that the error in question doesn't travel through my code. There is a similar one though that does travel through my code, and if you read my question you'll see that I've already printed it out, it appears to be a normal Font, Microsoft Sans Serif, which comes by default with XP. any more ideas?